# How To Programmatically Create & Pause Google App Engine Task Queues

Tags: java, google-app-engine, task, task-queue

I'm using Google App Engine and I've been using a named push queue to process some tasks. The queue was defined and configured using queue.xml. That's fine.

Now I'm trying to do more:

1) Is there a way to **dynamically create and configure** a new queue in Java "on the fly"?

2) Also, once I have a queue (either through queue.xml or 1) if possible), is there a way to **pause and resume the queue** in Java (just like you can do using the admin console buttons)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) since it has to be in the queue.xml and uploaded with your app, I can't think of a way to do it. As mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/queue#About_queue_xml): "An app can only add tasks to queues defined in queue.xml and the default queue."

2) in the same page, just a bit [further down](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/queue#Defining_Push_Queues_and_Processing_Rates), you can see that if you set the processing rate of 0, it will pause your queue. To resume, just change it back to something else.  Unfortunately that is all done through the xml, not through your code directly.

You might want to take this to Google's [Public Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) as a Feature Request.

Answer (score 0):

You can run "gcloud app deploy queue.yaml" in a [script](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/scripting-gcloud) to programmatically edit the queue.yaml which in turn creates / modifies Push Queues.