# Create TaskQueue programmatically

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

You can create Task queue through the *queue.xml* lie this:

```
<queue-entries>
    <queue>
        <name>default</name>
        <rate>5/s</rate>
    </queue>
</queue-entries>
```

But is there a way to create new Queue programmatically in Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Programmatically Create & Pause Google App Engine Task Queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372998/how-to-programmatically-create-pause-google-app-engine-task-queues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create [Queues dynamically](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-push-queues), however you can always run "gcloud app deploy queue.yaml" in a [script](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/scripting-gcloud) to programmatically edit the queue.yaml which in turn creates / modifies Push Queues.