# Creating a task (push) queue programmatically in google app engine using python/flask

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, flask

The docs on this aren't great. Really I want to find a way to create a task queue programmatically if it does not already exist without having to install the google cloud package locally and deploying a yaml that specifies the queues.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: this is not possible, at least not at this time.

The only way to create/update a task queue configuration, at least presently, is to deploy a queue configuration file with the corresponding information. From [Creating Push Queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-push-queues):

> To add queues or change the default configuration, edit the
>   `queue.yaml` file for your application, which you upload to App
>   Engine.

This can be scripted, qualifying in a sense as being done programmatically. See related [Create TaskQueue programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49447652/create-taskqueue-programmatically)

Technically (but most likely not what you're after) deploying the queue configuration file can also be done with a GAE language specific SDK, not only with the google cloud (`gcloud`) SDK.

Side note: you tagged your post with [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), which is only supported in the flexible environment, you should be aware of the [Task Queue limitations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#task_queue) in such case.

Comment: Thanks, especially with the link on limitations. Having a look it seems as though we cannot add tasks in the flexible environment to a push queue which is a real let down, as we use python3 on our backend.

Comment: That's changing, note the mentioning of the alpha availability in that section.

Comment: Yeah that's fine, although at this stage we can't commit to using an alpha for our prod activities.